# Bootstrap buttons with same height and vertically-centered text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 3 Bootstrap buttons side-by-side, but one of them has a line break (I'm modifying them with `white-space: normal`). I need them all to have the same height, and vertical-centered text.

I have them like this:
[image: current]

And I need them like this:
[image: desired]

I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/3224008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would something like this work for you?

```css
.option-button {
    height:100%;
}

.media-object {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/>
<div class="media-object pull-left">
    <button class="btn btn-info option-button">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary option-button">A<br/>B<br/>C</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info option-button">A</button>
</div>            

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

you can use `height: 100%;` on the buttons but with that, you need to set the height of the containing div. hope this helps!

Comment: Not responsive... just quick fix